# Какой layout лучше выбрать для JPane, чтобы разместить элементы таким образом?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jframe, jpanel

Планируется две панели. Первая панель с элементами, размеры которой не меняются.
На второй панели будут меняться размеры таблицы и по ней пока нет вопросов.

Обе панели размещаются на фрейме (JFrame) друг под другом.

Пробовал GroupLayout, но его настройка не дает возможности менять размеры элементов, а это очень важно!

[image: Две панели]

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью **GridBagLayout** вы можете без труда оперировать каждой ячейкой, в отличии от GridLayout.
Туториал: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html